Iris Plus Graphics G7
I'm trying to connect a 4k LG monitor externally, but I cannot get above 1920. Software can do it, but 24.10 out of the box can't.
*-display                 
     description: VGA compatible controller
     product: Iris Plus Graphics G7
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 2
     bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
     logical name: /dev/fb0
     version: 07
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
     configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=1920x1080 resolution=3840,2400 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
     resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:214 memory:603d000000-603dffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff


Damn, having to go back to windows to show a windows shop how Linux (Ubuntu) is better.
Nothing i have found or tried has worked - used to work fine in older Ubuntu.
That is not going to end well
